# How to get the asymptotic formula of generalized Bessel function?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, special-functions

How to get the asymptotic formula of generalized Bessel function?
$$J_{\nu}^{(\mu)}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\nu+1-1/\mu)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{\mu \nu/2}
\int_{0}^{1} (1-\tau^\mu)^{\nu-1/\mu}\cos z\tau\, \mathrm{d}\tau \quad \Re(\nu)>1/\mu-1,\ \mu\geqslant 1.$$
I can find the Bessel function in books, but I do not know the generalized Bessel function. Can you help me?

Comment: Are you interested in the asymptotic for $z \gg 1$ or...?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, Dou you know more about this function?

Comment: I believe it should be possible to obtain the asymptotic with the same method I used in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/764785/5531).