# How to get the asymptotic form of this oscilatting integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, singularity-theory, oscillatory-integral

So the integral is like this:
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos xt}{(x^2-1)\left[\left(\ln\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right|\right)^2+\pi^2\right]}\mathrm{d}x$$

**The question is how to get the asymptotic form of this integral when $t$ is very large.**

The integrand is a decaying oscilating function:

[image]

The denominator of the integrand is zero when $x\to 1$.

Honestly, I don't know whether this integral will converge, for it reminds me of the integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
which is $\infty$.

I hope it is a meaningful integral and the asymptotic can be obtained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a comment, but by mimicking the procedure in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/763857/5531) near the endpoint $x=1$ we can show that

$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos xt}{(x^2-1)\left[\left(\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^2+\pi^2\right]}\,dx \approx \operatorname{Re} \left\{ \frac{e^{it}}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-yt}}{y \left[\left(\log \frac{iy}{2}\right)^2 + \pi^2\right]}\,dy\right\}
$$

to first order as $t \to \infty$.  Numerically these agree very well; below is a plot of the left integral in red and the approximation in blue.

[image]

This image was created with the following code in Mathematica.  The program complains about the singularities in the integrands but ultimately it probably handles them alright.

```
pointSpacing = 1/5; (* decrease this for a higher resolution plot *)
Show[
 ListPlot[
  Table[{t, 
    Re[E^(I t)/2 NIntegrate[
        E^(-y t)/(y (Log[I y/2]^2 + Pi^2)), {y, 0, \[Infinity]}] // 
      Quiet]},
   {t, 30, 50, pointSpacing}],
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[
  Table[{t, 
    NIntegrate[
      Cos[x t]/((x^2 - 1) (Log[(x - 1)/(x + 1)]^2 + Pi^2)), {x, 
       1, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 20] // Quiet},
   {t, 30, 50, pointSpacing}],
  PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True]
 ]
```

Because of the slow $y \to 0$ logarithmic singularity in the denominator we lose a lot of numerical accuracy if we replace the denominator by a simpler approximation.  To first order the denominator is

$$
\sim \frac{1}{y(\log y)^2}
$$

near $y=0$, so if we replace the denominator with this in the integrand (and replace the integration interval $(0,\infty)$ with $(0,c)$ for some $0 < c < 1$) then we should still obtain the correct leading order behavior (but, again, it will be a worse approximation numerically).  Then, since the integral is real, we can use $\operatorname{Re} e^{it} = \cos t$ to obtain the approximation

$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos xt}{(x^2-1)\left[\left(\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^2+\pi^2\right]}\,dx \approx \frac{\cos t}{2} \int_0^c \frac{e^{-yt}}{y (\log y)^2}\,dy
$$

as $t \to \infty$.  Now we can use a result of Erdélyi (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1223177/5531)) to conclude that the leading order behavior should be

$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos xt}{(x^2-1)\left[\left(\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^2+\pi^2\right]}\,dx \approx \frac{\cos t}{2\log t}
$$

as $t \to \infty$.  It is important to note here that by ignoring complex contributions from the approximating integral we no longer accurately approximate the phase of the integral.  If higher-order corrections to this approximation were computed, terms of the form $o(1/\log t)\sin t$ will appear compensate for this.

Below is a plot of this $\cos t/2\log t$ approximation in blue versus the original integral in red.  As mentioned earlier, this is a worse approximation than before, but at least it captures the correct logarithmic decrease of the amplitude of the oscillation.

[image]

This image was created with the following code.

```
pointSpacing = 1/2; (*decrease this for a higher res plot*)
Show[
 Plot[Cos[t]/(2 Log[t]),
  {t, 570, 600},
  PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[
  Table[{t, 
    NIntegrate[
      Cos[x t]/((x^2 - 1) (Log[(x - 1)/(x + 1)]^2 + Pi^2)), {x, 
       1, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 20] // Quiet},
   {t, 570, 600, pointSpacing}],
  PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True]
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your "comment", I will look into it carefully soon. At this moment I would like to know how you obtain the numerical results? Using mathematica? Can you put the code snipit for future reader's convenience? What is the $t$ value you choose, I want to reproduce it myself. Thank you!

Comment: Haha, I forgot I started the post with that.  I ended up writing more than I expected :)  Yes to Mathematica.  I accidentally closed the window without saving the code but I'll write it up again this afternoon and include it in the post.

Comment: @buzhidao Included the code in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll reproduce it and follow your answer carefully!

Comment: I've reproduce all your calculations. Here is some questions:(1).If I expand the integrand by $1/\ln y$, the second leading term will not give a term of $\sin t /\ln t$, instead it give a $\sin t /(\ln t)^2$ term. (2). I think the $\pi ^2$ is essential, how to keep track of this? For if you delete this term in the first code snippt, you can see huge difference(3). How can I get the phase information, can you give me more hint?

Comment: (1) Right, I wrote $o(1/\log y)\sin t$, the $o(1/\log y)$ meaning something that decreases more quickly than $1/\log y$ as $y \to \infty$.  (2) Yes, the error introduced by ignoring the $\pi^2$ term are large, but still smaller than the leading order term.  (3) It will likely be difficult.  I would be interested to see a good answer to that too.

Comment: The leading order is actually quite satiesfactory for me. Thank you very much and I'll accept it. If in the near future I need more accuracy, I will put another post or start a bounty for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer to the problem, but only concerns the question of whether the integral converges.

With change of variable $x=1+y$ :
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos xt}{(x^2-1)\left[\left(\ln\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right|\right)^2+\pi^2\right]}\mathrm{d}x =
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (1+y)t}{y(1+2y)\left[\left(\ln\left|\frac{y}{2+y}\right|\right)^2+\pi^2\right]}\mathrm{d}y
$$
In $y>0$ close to $0$ :
$$ \frac{\cos (1+y)t}{y(1+2y)\left[\left(\ln\left|\frac{y}{2+y}\right|\right)^2+\pi^2\right]} \sim \frac{\cos(t)}{y\left(\ln(y) \right)^2}$$
$\int \frac{1}{y\left(\ln(y) \right)^2}dy = -\frac{1}{\ln(y)}$ which tends to $0$ when $y$ tends to $0$. So, the integral is convergent for the lower bound.

$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos xt}{(x^2-1)\left[\left(\ln\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right|\right)^2+\pi^2\right]}\mathrm{d}x$ obviously is convergent  in $x$ tending to infinity.

So, the answer is : The integral is convergent.

Comment: Very nice argument, I am glad that it coverages.